# Change tab title in colorbox frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox for my web application and when I display an html/php file in a colorbox frame, the command `window.document.title = "test";` does not work anymore. Has anyone a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Please describe what do you mean by "does not work". Perhaps you're looking for `window.top.document.title`?

Comment: window.top.document.title does not work either....i mean when i run document.title = "test" in a normal html file it just changes the tab title but if im doing this in a colorbox frame the command does not change the tab title anymore.